# Script to check number of Established connections, then restart application if too many connections

Tags: bash

For some testing, I need to count the amount of open, Established connections, then restart the application holding them open, if the count of open connections is above a certain value.

I've tried a few different options I grabbed off the internet, but none seem consistent in behavior.  I've had some that restart the service no matter what, and some that sometimes restart, and sometimes don't, which I also find quite odd.

I've only just started poking around at scripting, and I could really use some help in how to do this, if anyone would be so kind as to lend a hand.

One example used:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
netstat -tlpan | grep -i netservice | grep EST | wc -l
if [ $? > 40 ]
then
    /opt/netservice/netservice.py stop; /opt/netservice/netservice.py start
fi
```

What I'm trying to do is allow a certain amount of connections to build up, and then when the total hits above a certain value, recycle the application (aka: start/stop).

This is in no way the way this should behave going forward -- again, this is just for testing something else.

Comment: What's wrong with the example you provided? It's certainly not particularly elegant, but what exactly do you need help with here?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Before I refreshed the page, the formatting looked like it removed all of the indents and new lines.  Sorry for the confusion -- total newb moment.

Comment: It did "remove" all the indents / linebreaks. The question looks different now because tripleee edited it.

Comment: shellcheck.net looks great.  gonna give that a shot.

Comment: Funnily enough shellcheck gets this one wrong. `> 40` is not a comparison at all; it redirects output to a file called `40`.

Comment: Yes!  I just noticed that it looked wrong to me as well.  I was just about to look that up via the googles.   Any ideas about how to do that comparison in the meanwhile?  Thanks again.

Comment: I switched that line to the following:

if [ $? -gt "40" ]; then

but, it doesn't seem to do anything.  Just keeps the application running and echoes out the number of connections.

Comment: I think I got it to work.  I switched the threshold value and the netstat output value to variables, and then change the if line to the following:

`if [ "$var2" -gt $var1 ]; then`

Comment: The `$?` is the exit status of the application, not the output of an application. Grab the output with command substitution. `cnt=$(..... wc -l)`.